# Passing a variable argument to Python from Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7

I need to call Python code form Matlab. I need to pass it a variable value.

What I am doing in the Matlab file now is :

```
input1 = "My Input"
!python.exe pythonFileName.py input1
```

But the pythonFileName.py file reads the value of the input as "input1" as not as "My Input". I need to pass the value "My Input" to the Python file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically build the string based on the *contents* of the `input1` variable, not on the *name* of the variable. Then use the [`system`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) function (which is like `!`) with that string:

```
system(['python.exe pythonFileName.py ' input1])
```